# UnixTree (XTree for Unix Systems) does not appear in color

Tags: command-line, colors, xterm

I am trying to use UnixTree (www.unixtree.org) on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS via the Ubuntu Terminal.

If I run the application "xt" I get the following error:

```
$ xt
No term file or database entry found for term "xterm-256color"
xt: cannot initialize terminal.
```

I got around this error by setting:

```
$ export TERM=xterm
$ xt
```

And the application starts. However, it starts in the same color scheme as the terminal itself, which makes the application unusable since the color highlighting of selection is critical to its use as seen in image [here](http://www.unixtree.org/docs/uxt_sc_l.gif).

Screenshot of my view:
[UnixTree-NoColor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExLbj.jpg)

I tried launching the application using the following option according to the UnixTree manual:

```
$ xt +w
```

Which should launch UnixTree in a new window, with full color and mouse functionality but it does not work, the application still opens in the same window without color.

I also tried launching the application from xterm itself, but it appears black/white as well, same as xterm itself.

However, I prefer to use Ubuntu Terminal at this time.

Anyone have any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: very similar to http://askubuntu.com/questions/576318/how-to-add-xterm-to-terminfo and the same solution applies.  this old program expects terminfo files in one location; modern linuxes store them somewhere else.  copy or link them back.  (works with `xterm-256color` as well.)

Comment: @quixotic: Thanks! that worked, but it took some trying and further googling. Particularly because the solution had a missing "/" at the end. The command states: `sudo cp /lib/terminfo/x/xterm /usr/share/terminfo/x` which copies the xterm info to a file named "x". What i needed was: `sudo cp /lib/terminfo/x/xterm /usr/share/terminfo/x/` which creates a folder "x" and places the term info there, which is where the applications expects to find it. For the record, I copied the `xterm-256color` file over that solved my problem!

Comment: @shreyas The OP there already has `/usr/share/terminfo/x` as a directory, which is why they could use that command. In your case, the directory probably didn't exist before this.

Comment: i haven't tested it, but symlinking or bind-mounting `/lib/terminfo` to `/usr/share/terminfo` might be a more thorough solution.

Comment: @muru, yes that makes sense, i did not have that folder.

Comment: @quixotic: That's a good idea. I will look into that.

Comment: @muru: I would't say that this question is an exact duplicate, although the solution is the same as another question.

Comment: @shreyas being marked a duplicate isn't a slight on the question; it helps folks searching on similar problems boil down to the root issue (in this case, `terminfo` problems with old software).

Comment: @quixotic, understood! Thanks for informing me!
I appreciate the help and guidance.